# Javascript conditional hide/show issue

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

I need some help with some javascript logic.  I have this code which hides/shows.  I need to it to work if any of the or conditions are met. it is currently working for the first two conditions. I am fairly new to javascript so not sure if I am writing the conditions correctly.

javascript:

```
$("input[name=JECT]").click(function() {
        if ((this.value == "no" || this.value == "JECTindividual_electronic") || document.getElementById("JECTRenewal")== "yes")
           $('#JECTvolumeshow').slideUp();
         else $('#JECTvolumeshow').slideDown();
    });
```

here is the html:

```
<h2>Subscription Options</h2>
<h3>Please choose the options you desire.</h3>

    <div id="JECTshow" style="display:none">
    <p style="text-indent:30px;">Length of subscription:</br>
            <label><input type="radio" name="JECTsub" value="1" checked <?php if(@$JECTsub=="1"){ echo "checked";}?>> 1 year</label></br>
            <label><input type="radio" name="JECTsub" value="2" <?php if(@$JECTsub=="2"){ echo "checked";}?>> 2 years</label></br>
            <label><input type="radio" name="JECTsub" value="3" <?php if(@$JECTsub=="3"){ echo "checked";}?>> 3 years</label></br>
            <label><input type='checkbox' name='JECTrenewal' value='yes' <?php if(@$JECTrenewal=="yes"){ echo "checked";}?>> Check box if this is a renewal</label></p></br>
            <div id="JECTvolumeshow" style="display:none">
            <p style="text-indent:30px;">I would like my subscription to start with:</br></p>
            <label><input type="radio" name="JECTvolume" value="current" checked<?php if(@$JECTvolume=="current"){ echo "checked";}?>><?php echo "Volume ".$JECTsubscribeVolume['vol'].", Year ".$JECTsubscribeVolume['year']?></label></br>
            <label><input type="radio" name="JECTvolume" value="next"<?php if(@$JECTvolume=="next"){ echo "checked";}?>><?php echo "Volume ".++$JECTsubscribeVolume['vol'].", Year ".++$JECTsubscribeVolume['year']?></label></p>
           </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You can't compare a DOM element to a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.getElementById("JECTRenewal")` returns a DOM node, not any single property of the element.  Therefore you wouldn't directly compare it to `"yes"`.  To see if the checkbox is checked, set `JECTrenewal` as the id of the element and look for the `checked` attribute:

```
if ((this.value == "no" || this.value == "JECTindividual_electronic") 
    || document.getElementById("JECTrenewal").checked)
 ...
```

Or, using jQuery:

```
if ((this.value == "no" || this.value == "JECTindividual_electronic") 
    || $("input[name=JECTrenewal]").is(":checked"))
 ...
```

Comment: This answer is correct, but in addition to this, the element has a name attribute of "JECTRenewal" but not an id of "JECTRenewal". He will have to make it an id as well for this to work.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I still can't get it. I have added altered the html as follows:   `code<label><input type="checkbox" name="JECTrenewal" id="JECTrenewal" value='yes' <?php if(@$JECTrenewal=="yes"){ echo "checked";}?>> Check box if this is a renewal</label></p></br>`   and implemented the suggested changes. Neither of them work, but do not return an error either.

Comment: @learning_curve Element names and IDs are case sensitive. I capitalized an extra R.  Code fixed.

Comment: This is what eventually worked for me.  I believe Matt had a correct answer but it just didn't work for me - still not sure why - maybe the way I had some other stuff written.
  '$("input[name=JECT], #JECTrenewal").click(function() {
            var JECTrenewal=document.getElementById('JECTrenewal').value;
            var JECT = $("input[name=JECT]:checked").val();
           if ( JECT == "no" || JECT == "JECTindividual_electronic" || $("input[name=JECTrenewal]").is(":checked") )
                $('#JECTvolumeshow').slideUp();
            else $('#JECTvolumeshow').slideDown();
     });'

Answer (score 1):

document.getElementById will return null when an id that's not in the DOM is used as a parameter. so is the following code what you want?

```js
$("input[name=JECT]").click(function() {
        if (this.value == "no" || this.value == "JECTindividual_electronic" || document.getElementById("JECTRenewal") !== null)
           $('#JECTvolumeshow').slideUp();
         else $('#JECTvolumeshow').slideDown();
    });
```

If you're looking to compare what the text content of that element is, it's probably easiest to use jquery, like so:

```js
$("input[name=JECT]").click(function() {
        if (this.value == "no" || this.value == "JECTindividual_electronic") || $("#JECTRenewal").text() == "yes")
           $('#JECTvolumeshow').slideUp();
         else $('#JECTvolumeshow').slideDown();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

When using jquery you must select "this" in jquery fashion **ex. $(this)** ; also you must use **.val() instead of value** .

Example .

```
  $("input[name=JECT]").click(function() {

            if ( $(this).val() == "no" || $(this).val() == "JECTindividual_electronic" || $("#JECTRenewal").text() == "yes"){

               $('#JECTvolumeshow').slideUp();

            } else {

               $('#JECTvolumeshow').slideDown();

            }


        });
```

Fyi I've corrected a few other small issues also in this code ...

hope this helps .